# how to count rows from a column while using group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im stuck in count problem. Can anyone have a look into my below code and tell me how to count from the first while loop, which is $query. Here is two column grouped by, I just want to add another column name without grouping only to count rows. Like

```
"SELECT CountryCode,NetID,COUNT(OpCode) as count FROM activecon WHERE OpCode='$thisActiveOp' GROUP BY CountryCode,NetID"
```

I tried the above but i don't know how to echo this COUNT(OpCode) with my bottom code where I echo my table row with $countryValue and $networkValue.

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT CountryCode,NetID FROM activecon WHERE OpCode='$thisActiveOp' GROUP BY CountryCode,NetID") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr><td>$thisActiveOp</td>";

    $networkID = $row['NetID'];
    $countryID = $row['CountryCode'];


    $query2=mysql_query("SELECT countryName,networkName FROM connection_details WHERE countryId='$countryID' AND netId='$networkID'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
        $countryValue = $row2['countryName'];
        $networkValue = $row2['networkName'];
    }
echo "<td>$countryValue</td><td>$networkValue</td></tr>";

}
```

Comment: To echo it out you use the alias name (you have used `as count` to give the column an alias name of count

Comment: Why can't you just use your first snippet of SQL, and write something like `$count = $row['count'];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you suggested should work, so it will be:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT CountryCode,NetID,COUNT(OpCode) as code FROM activecon WHERE OpCode='$thisActiveOp' GROUP BY CountryCode,NetID") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr><td>$thisActiveOp</td>";

    $networkID = $row['NetID'];
    $countryID = $row['CountryCode'];
    $code      = $row['code'];


    $query2=mysql_query("SELECT countryName,networkName FROM connection_details WHERE countryId='$countryID' AND netId='$networkID'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
        $countryValue = $row2['countryName'];
        $networkValue = $row2['networkName'];
    }
    echo "<td>$countryValue</td><td>$networkValue</td><td>$code</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alias name to access the count from the returned array from mysql.

However depending on the details of your data your script / sql can probably be simplified to this (ie assuming that there is just 1 record on connection_details for each record on activecon):-

```
<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT b.countryName, b.networkName, COUNT(a.OpCode) AS `count`
                    FROM activecon a
                    INNER JOIN connection_details b
                    ON a.CountryCode = b.countryId AND a.NetID = b.netId
                    WHERE a.OpCode='".mysq_real_escape_string($thisActiveOp)."' 
                    GROUP BY b.countryName, b.networkName") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    echo "<tr><td>$thisActiveOp</td><td>".$row['countryName']."</td><td>".$row['networkName']."</td><td>".$row['count']."</td></tr>";
}
```